# prevent DOM parser from parsing tags which are not enclosed

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I prevent DOM parser from parsing tags which are not enclosed, with JavaScript?

for example  `<h1> Hello World` when I use  `parser.parseFromString("<h1> Hello World", "text/html");` , I'm getting a node which is `<h1>Hello World</h1>`.

Comment: Parse will try to fix invalid structure. Why would you want prevent it from doing it?

Comment: @dfsq I'm trying to build DOM trees from strings, and then traverse them for comparison. I'm developing this for a website with some simple HTML exercises, which a user might submit **wrong/incomplete input**, which then I compare with **correct answer** for validation...

Comment: You should probably use a custom parser meeting your requirements.